# How to ignore some fields in river mongodb and elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use river mongo to bind a mongodb collection to elastic search.

This results in every field in mongo collection will be saved in elasticseach index.

I want to know how to ignore some fields, don't let it save in elastic index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up mongodb river, you can exclude certain fields, e.g.

```
 "mongodb": {
        "db": "YourDbName",
        "collection": "YourCollectionName",
        "options": {
              "exclude_fields": "name_of_field_to_be_ignored"
            }
    },
```

Comment: thanks. If there's serval fields like (a,b,c), then use  "exclude_fields": "a,b,c" or "exclude_fields": ["a","b","c"], which is correct?

Comment: List is your answer:
[ES River MongoDB example](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/blob/master/manual-testing/issues/76/mongodb-river-simple.json)

Answer (score 0):

I got another method from river mongo wiki. by using script, you can customize..However, you should set disable script to be false in elasticsearch.yml .

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki

```
$ curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/mongoscriptfilter/_meta" -d'
{
  "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
      "db": "testmongo", 
      "collection": "documents", 
      "script": "ctx.document.title = ctx.document.title_from_mongo; delete ctx.document.title_from_mongo;"
    },
    "index": {
      "name": "testmongo", 
      "type": "documents"
    }
}'
```